# why the scrapy yield.Request() did not Recursive？

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

here is my code?

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'quotes'
allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com/']
start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com//']

def parse(self, response):
    quotes = response.css('.quote')
    for quote in quotes:
        item = QuoteItem()
        text = quote.css('.text::text').extract_first()
        author = quote.css('.author::text').extract_first()
        tags = quote.css('.tags .tag::text').extract()
        item['text'] = text
        item['author'] = author
        item['tags'] = tags
        yield item

    next = response.css('.pager .next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    url = response.urljoin(next)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

I am new to scrapy. I think this will always Recursive.But actually it didn't.That's why?

Comment: what do you mean with recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that `scrapy` uses `allowed_domains` as a regex for determining if the links passing through belong to the specified domain.

just change the string `quotes.toscrape.com/` to `quotes.toscrape.com` if you only want to allow requests from that specific subdomain.

You can also remove that entire variable if you want to allow requests from every domain.